# Pyhton How to use PyQt6's QTcpSocket?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am quite a newbie to PyQt so forgive me if my questoin is stupid.
I was wondering how can I use QTcpSocket to make connection to the server on localhost and send and receive messages.
I have a simple Qt application with a MainWindow. When clicked on the login button the socket must connect to the server and send the login information. the server then responds to the client and if successful the client can enter chat room and start chatting with others. so what I basically need is a way to implement this simple logic in a nonblocking way (nonblocking because I have a loading animation that I want to spin while the connection is being made.).

Comment: Sorry but we don't generally answer to questions asking "Can you tell me how to do XYZ", unless followed by something like "my research resulted in ABC but I don't understand how `abc` works" and/or "I've tried 012 but didn't work" (and then showing that 012). Have you tried something? If yes, then provide a [mre] (please *do* read that) of your attempts, even if it doesn't work or doesn't do what expected. If not, please remember that SO is not a tutorial website nor a coding service: we don't provide code on request, nor answers to questions that don't show sufficient research efforts.

Comment: I suggest you to carefully read [ask] and also review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648). Note that if you want to provide a [mre], you shouldn't rush it; creating a good example takes time, but it's **always** worth the effort: it allows us to focus on the problem instead of being distracted by irrelevant issues (it may even help you find the answer on your own), meaning that more people may be attracted by your post, thus increasing the possibility of getting one or more valid answers. Take your time: while rushing sometimes help, it mostly doesn't, and usually worsen things.